# How to create a jar client with .java files in it with wsimport

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, wsimport

I am trying to create a jar client with wsimport but when it runs it creates a jar that contains only class files in it.

Is it possible to create jar with also .java files in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following command. Wsimport utility deletes the java files after generation.

```
wsimport -s src <wsdl url>
```

Comment: I want .java files in the jar file not on an outer directory

Comment: This doesn't work. It only has .class files in jar file.

Comment: You can refer this link. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html

Comment: The `-keep` option keeps the .java files.